# Conexão banco de dados Sybase com c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, sybase

Tenho um arquivo de banco de dados Sybase em minha maquina, quero disponibilizar esse banco para ter acesso em minha aplicação c#, como disponibilizo esse arquivo de banco de dados Sybase, e como acesso esse banco com c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o "[SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/pdf/dbprogramming12.pdf)"

Você pode baixa-lo pelo Nuget e existem duas versões:

Para o ASA16: [iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5/)

Para o ASA2017: [Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere/)

Exemplo:

```
SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("Data Source=SQL Anywhere 12 Demo");
conn.Open();
SACommand cmd = new SACommand("SELECT Surname FROM Employees", conn);
SADataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
listEmployees.BeginUpdate();
while (reader.Read())
{
    listEmployees.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
listEmployees.EndUpdate();
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Mas como disponibilizo o meu banco de dados, pois tenho o arquivo, gostaria de saber como faço para ter acesso a ele. Aqui vc informa o data "source new SAConnection("Data Source=SQL Anywhere 12 Demo")", aonde na minha ou oq configuro na minha maquina para esse banco ficar acessivel na minha aplicação? você saberia me informar?

Comment: Aonde especifico o caminho do meu banco de dados?

Comment: O Sybase SQL Anywhere  é como qualquer outro banco de dados gerenciad0(PostgreSql, MySql, MSSqlServer),vovêprecisa instalar um servidor. https://www.sap.com/brazil/products/sql-anywhere.html

Comment: Uma ultima informação, se eu tenho uma conexão odbc em outro servidor ja funcionando, como monto a string de conexão para acessar esse banco q esta em outro servidor?

Comment: No exemplo da resposta `Data Source=SQL Anywhere 12 Demo`, o **SQL Anywhere 12 Demo** é o DSN ODBC. Você cria um ODBC (sim a SAP ainda não evoluiu) na maquina cliente e usa o DSN na connection string.